# How to emulate GL_DEPTH_CLAMP_NV?

Tags: opengl-es, shader, depth

I have a platform where this extension is not available ( non NVIDIA ). 
How could I emulate this functionality ? 
I need it to solve far plane clipping problem when rendering stencil shadow volumes with z-fail algorithm.

Comment: I am trying to emulate this extension in the fragment shader with  
`gl_FragDepth = clamp( gl_FragCoord.z, gl_DepthRange.near, gl_DepthRange.far );`  but it is not working as it should.

Comment: The reason why clamping the output z-value doesn't work is because the triangle rasterization rules prevents fragments from being generated in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Since you say you're using OpenGL ES, but also mentioned trying to clamp gl_FragDepth, I'm assuming you're using OpenGL ES 2.0, so here's a shader trick:

You can emulate ARB_depth_clamp by using a separate varying for the z-component.

Vertex Shader:

```
varying float z;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = ftransform();

    // transform z to window coordinates
    z = gl_Position.z / gl_Position.w;
    z = (gl_DepthRange.diff * z + gl_DepthRange.near + gl_DepthRange.far) * 0.5;

    // prevent z-clipping
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
varying float z;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(z), 1.0);
    gl_FragDepth = clamp(z, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Would it be correct to clamp z already in vertex shader? Would it help performance?

Answer (score 1):

"Fall back" to [`ARB_depth_clamp`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/depth_clamp.txt)?

Check if [`NV_depth_clamp`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/depth_clamp.txt) exists anyway?  For example my ATI card supports five "NVidia-only" GL extensions.